# Importing DER encoded private key using GnuTLS library fails

Tags: c, file, private-key, der, gnutls

I need to import a private key (.der format) to the gnutls_x509_privkey_t structure. For that, I first parsed the DER private key file into char[] using file operations. Then I have used gnutls_x509_privkey_import2 API to import the private key (char[]).

While importing, it returns with an error "**ASN1 parser: Error in DER parsing**".

***Note:*** When I try to parse the PEM encoded private key instead of using DER, the import API works fine. Am I making any mistake at the parsing of a DER file to char[] or is there a way to parse DER file?

Also, I **don't want to use gnutls_load_file API** to load the DER private key.

I have attached the sample code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <gnutls/gnutls.h>
#include <gnutls/x509.h>
#include <gnutls/abstract.h>

int main()
{
char key_der[1675];
char file_to_char;
FILE *fptr;
int length;
gnutls_x509_privkey_t pkey;
int ret;
gnutls_datum_t key;

ret = gnutls_x509_privkey_init(&pkey);
if (ret < 0) {
    printf("gnutls_x509_privkey_init: %d\n", ret);
}

if ((fptr = fopen("<privatekey_filename>.der", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error! opening file\n");
    // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
    exit(1);
}

int i = 0;
file_to_char = fgetc(fptr);
while (file_to_char != EOF)
{
    key_der[i] = file_to_char;
    i++;
    file_to_char = fgetc(fptr);
}
key_der[i] = EOF;

key.data = (void *) key_der;
key.size = i;

ret = gnutls_x509_privkey_import2(pkey, &key, GNUTLS_X509_FMT_DER, NULL, 0);
if (ret < 0) {
    printf("\nret value = %d\n", ret);
    printf("gnutls_x509_privkey_import2: %s\n", gnutls_strerror(ret));
}

fclose(fptr);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Couple of obvious issues: (1) `file_to_char` definitely needs to be type `int`, particularly with binary files, otherwise you have no way to distinguish `EOF` from a valid byte with the same bit pattern - using `fread()` may be easier here; (2) you should be using `"rb"` as the mode for `fopen()`, although this shouldn't make any difference on a POSIX system.

Comment: Thanks you so much Paul. It worked and now I'm able to import the private key.